# django python social auth send email

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am using python social auth for login. After user is created I want to send the user a email. For this I am writing a custom pipeline

```
def send_confirmation_email(strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
if user:
    if kwargs['is_new']:
        template = "email/social_registration_confirm.html"
        subject = "Account Confirmation"
        email = user.email
        print(user.username)
        username = user.username
        kwargs.update(subject=subject, email=email, username=username)
        notification_email.delay(template, **kwargs)
```

I am using `celery` to send email. When I send email it gives me error saying `<UserSocialAuth: some_username> is not JSON serializable`

Why I am getting this error. `notification_email` works for other email sending functionality.

Need suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) accepts only a few datatypes: null, arrays, booleans, numbers, strings, and objects.

So, anything else should be expressed as one of these types.

My guess is that `**kwargs` that you are sending in to `notification_email` contains a data type that cannot be expressed as JSON.

To solve this problem, send only needed arguments, not the whole `**kwargs`.

I would create a dictionary and include everything there:

```
var args = dict()

args['username'] = username
args['template'] = template
# other arguments

notification_email.delay(args)
```

I hope it helps.